# click() jquery через $.post или $.get

Tags: javascript, jquery

Здравствуйте, есть код:

```
var url = "http://steamcommunity.com/id/foozzylalka";
$.get(url, function(data){

  var hide = $('.persona_level', data).size();

    if (hide > 0) {

        var cs_go = $('div.game_info_cap a', data).attr('href').split('/')[4];

        if (cs_go == "730") {

            /* accept */

        }else{ /* block */ }

    }else{ /* block */ }

  $('#wrapper').html(cs_go);

});
```

Так вот, там где /* accept */, мне нужно как то нажать на кнопку.

[image: Картинка (image) :D]

При открытой вкладке я делал это через document:

`document.getElementsByClassName('btn_profile_action:first').click();`

А как это реализовать через запрос ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил проблему по другому. Функция отправляла данные на php файл через ajax. Так что я просто скопировал себе ajax запрос и подставил нужные параметры.

Answer (score 3):

Может быть вам

```
$('selector').click();
```

поможет

Comment: Нет. Т.к. Я простым образом получаю код страницы в переменную data. Т.е. вызывать событие я должен на другой странице.

Comment: Сначала нужно встроить код в DOM, а потом уже пытаться имитировать событие.

Comment: В том и дело, что я не знаю как это сделать. Не подскажете ?

Comment: $('#wrapper').html(cs_go); до имитации события

Answer (score 2):

`$('selector').toggle();` - это имитация нажатия кнопки.